# Struts interceptor when need to be declare in struts.xml

Tags: java, struts2

I am new in Struts. I have found by google that before using interceptor you need to declare it in struts xml, but I have seen model driven, validation and workflow interceptors are not needed to declare in struts xml file . I am very confused that when we need to declare it in struts xml and when not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare it if it isn't declared in any other Struts 2 config file. The framework's own artifacts are declared in its default configuration.

Not very confusing.

Comment: What is struts2 config file ? is it Struts.xml. if yes then i am not seeing any such type of declaration

Comment: @user2130718 That's your *app's* config file, not the framework's default configuration. I'd consider spending some time on the S2 wiki, this information is all available in the guides for example, http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/struts-defaultxml.html

Comment: I have seen model driven interface    http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.14.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ModelDriven.java#ModelDriven and found that it does not implements com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor then why we need to implement this interface while creating custom interceptor ?

Comment: @user2130718 ... What makes you think `ModelDriven`, an interface, is an interceptor? It isn't; it's an interface. I'm begging you to read through some docs before going much further--you're in over your head.